# how to update foreign key value in child table using hibernate

Tags: hibernate

i have a parent table and child table and Given OneToOne relationship to them...so when i add some records to child table the pimary key value of parent table(assume that this table having some records already) i want to add in my child table... how i can achieve it using hibenate.. any help..

this is my parent bean---

```
package com.valto.workflow.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_WFProcessStatus_MST")
public class WorkFlowProcessStatus implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5508699872054752924L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="WFPStatusId")
    private long WFPStatusId;
    @Column(name="WFPStatusName")
    private String WFPStatusName;
    @Column(name="WFPStatusColor")
    private String WFPStatusColor;

    public long getWFPStatusId() {
        return WFPStatusId;
    }
    public void setWFPStatusId(int wFPStatusId) {
        WFPStatusId = wFPStatusId;
    }
    public String getWFPStatusName() {
        return WFPStatusName;
    }
    public void setWFPStatusName(String wFPStatusName) {
        WFPStatusName = wFPStatusName;
    }
    public String getWFPStatusColor() {
        return WFPStatusColor;
    }
    public void setWFPStatusColor(String wFPStatusColor) {
        WFPStatusColor = wFPStatusColor;
    }



}
```

this is my child class

```
package com.valto.workflow.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_workflow_process_details")
public class WorkFlowProcessDetails implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4355499783855489148L;
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int WFProcessId;

    @Column(name="WFProcessDate")
    private String WFProcessDate;

    @Column(name="ProcessComment")
    private String ProcessComment;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="WFPStatusId")
    private WorkFlowProcessStatus workflowprocessstatus;
    @OneToOne




    public int getWFProcessId() {
        return WFProcessId;
    }

    public void setWFProcessId(int wFProcessId) {
        WFProcessId = wFProcessId;
    }


    public String getWFProcessDate() {
        return WFProcessDate;
    }

    public void setWFProcessDate(String wFProcessDate) {
        WFProcessDate = wFProcessDate;
    }

    public String getProcessComment() {
        return ProcessComment;
    }

    public void setProcessComment(String processComment) {
        ProcessComment = processComment;
    }

    public WorkFlowProcessStatus getWorkflowprocessstatus() {
        return workflowprocessstatus;
    }

    public void setWorkflowprocessstatus(WorkFlowProcessStatus workflowprocessstatus) {
        this.workflowprocessstatus = workflowprocessstatus;
    }

}
```

and this my code for saving records in chld class....

```
public int saveWorkFlowProcessDetails(String wFProcessDate,

        String processComment) {
    Session sess=SessionFactoryCode.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try
    {
            WorkFlowProcessDetails wfpd=new WorkFlowProcessDetails();//child class object
            wfpd.setWFProcessDate(wFProcessDate);
            wfpd.setProcessComment(processComment);
            sess.beginTransaction();
            sess.save(wfpd);
            WorkFlowProcessStatus wfps=new WorkFlowProcessStatus();//parent class object
            wfpd.setWorkflowprocessstatus(wfps);
            sess.update(wfpd);
            sess.getTransaction().commit();


            return 1;


    }
    catch(QueryException ex)
    {
        ex.getMessage();
        sess.getTransaction().rollback();
        sess.close();
        return 0;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should cascade `workflowprocessstatus` so that It will be persisted when `WorkFlowProcessDetails` is updated/saved.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_workflow_process_details")
public class WorkFlowProcessDetails implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4355499783855489148L;

...

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="WFPStatusId")
private WorkFlowProcessStatus workflowprocessstatus;
```